# Javascript Angular resolve chain of promises before returning a result value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'm using a chain of promises in angular and I would like that at the end of the chain a value should be returned:

```
this.calculateeventsattended = function(username) {
   var Attendees = Parse.Object.extend("Attendees");
   var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
   var count_pres = 0
   query1 = new Parse.Query(Attendees);
   query1.equalTo("user_id",username);
   query1.equalTo("presence",true)        

   var promise = query1.count(function(count){
       count_pres = count
   }).then(function(){
       query2 = new Parse.Query(User);
       query2.equalTo("username",username);
       query2.first().then(function(object){
           alert("parse" + count_pres)
           object.set("events_attended",count_pres)
           object.save()
       })
   })
$q.all(promise)
return count_pres
}
```

the chain 'promise' is not resolved before the return is passed: count_pres is returned before the  $q.all(promise) is finished. Any idea?

Comment: Instead of `$q.all(promise) return count_pres` use `return $q.all(promise)`

Comment: it does not work: in that case the entire promise chain will be returned instead of only the value count_pres

Comment: return the combined promises instead of returning count_pres just as @varit05 said, and handle assigning of values outside of that function. Promises are asynchronous

Comment: NOT POSSIBLE. You can only return a promise. Not a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't imagine this will ever work? This is how you chain promises vs how to write async promises.

```
function chainedPromises() {
    return $q(function(resolve) {
        query
            .firstPromise()
            .then(function(firstResult) {
                return query.secondPromise(firstResult.something);
            })
            .then(function(secondResult) {
                return query.thirdPromise(secondResult.something);
            })
            .then(function(thirdResult) {
                return query.fourthPromise(thirdResult.something);
            })
            .then(function(fourthResult) {
                resolve(fourthResult);
            });
    });
}

function asyncPromises() {
    var promises = [];

    promises.push(query.firstPromise());
    promises.push(query.secondPromise());
    promises.push(query.thirdPromise());
    promises.push(query.fourthPromise());

    return $q.all(promises);
}

chainedPromises()
    .then(function(fourthResult) {
        doSomethingWith(fourthResult);
    });

asyncPromises()
    .then(function(results) {
       doSomethingWith(results); 
    });
```

Comment: ok I see you still need a promise to get an output of the promise. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. When you want to chain promises, you can by simply returning another promise in the `then` function.But you should only use it when you need data to continue the flow. If simply all data is required, you should use `$q.all`.